$f:X \to X$, a bijection, and $A \subseteq X$, Assume $f(A) \subseteq A$, then $f|_A$ is a bijection
Let $f:X \to X$ be a bijection, where $A \subseteq X$. Now if we asssume that $f(A) \subseteq A$, then $f|_A$ is a bijection
It is easy to prove that $f$ is $1$ to $1$, but I am unable to prove that f is Onto.
I would appreciate any help.
Note: This is a wrong assumption, counterexample given by @davidlui in answer

Usually, $f|_A : A \to X$, which wouldn't be a bijection unless $A=X$.  Even if you define $f|_A : A \to A$, it may not be.  The closest you can get is it is a bijection onto its image (i.e. the same as being an injection)

To be explicit, my point with the previous comment is this: how do you define $f|_A$?  What is the domain?  What is the codomain?

Domain will be A and the codomain will be f(A), which is a subset of A here...

If the codomain is $f(A)$, then it's trivially onto (regardless of whether it's a subset of $A$ or not).

Yes... Here codomain is A, so it need not be onto in general by the example given by @davidLui

If $A$ is a finite set, though, then it is true.  (Because in general, a one-to-one function from a finite set to itself is a bijection.)

This is not true. Let $X = \mathbb{Z}$ and $f(x) = x+1$. Let $A = \{n \in \mathbb{Z} : n \geq 0\}$. Then, $f$ is a bijection, $f(A) \subseteq A$, but $f|_A$ is not a bijection.
